# Navigating Between Documentation Tags is Difficult

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Documentation has just came out, and I'm already finding myself using it — not just to contribute, but actually consuming it as well. Unfortunately, I'm finding it difficult to navigate between tags. If I want to jump between tags (say `C Language` and `C++ Language`), I have to follow this painfully slow process:

1. Find the "Documentation <sup>Beta</sup>" link hiding up there by "Questions" (at first, I usually end up clicking on the tag name again).
2. Scroll to find / type the name of the tag I'm looking for.
3. Click on it.

By then, I may have forgotten why I wanted to jump to a different tag.

Compare this to the current tag navigation system. If I want to switch tags there, I do this:

1. Notice the obvious box where there is the tag name that all the questions are under.
2. Delete that tag and type my new tag.
3. Profit.

Alternatively, I can just search `[tag-name]` and it works.

Can we have a similarly easy way to navigate Documentation?

Comment: They could even have a small section with related tags, related topics, ...

Comment: Or a list of topics a user is following, like it is already the case with StackOverflow.